# mosquitto remap local topic (no bridge)

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am using `eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.9` and would like to remap incoming messages to topic `/registration_app` to `/$share/registration_app`.

In this case IoT devices will be publishing registration messages to `/registration_app` & backend ap will be listening and processing each request. To scale backend process horizontally, I want to switch to `/$share/registration_app` (**MQTT V5.0**) for backend process, but don't want to change original incoming message topic `/registration_app`.

SO far I can see remapping is available in case of bridging. So would like to know if I can do remapping without bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is really bad practice to start topics with leading `/`. It adds a null entry to the start of the topic tree and causes problems with things like shared subscriptions (we will get to that next).

Second, I think you have miss understood how [shared subscriptions](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt5-essentials-part7-shared-subscriptions/) work. Topics that start with `$share/` (note the lack of leading `/`) are used to set up shared subscription groups, so groups of clients can load balance the consuming of messages published to a give topic pattern. You don't do any topic remapping yourself.

To set up a shared subscription group you subscribe to a topic as follows:

```
$share/<groupname>/<topic>
```

So in your case assuming a group called `backend` and messages published to 'registration_app' (again note the lack of leading `/`) it would be

```
$share/backend/registration_app
```

If you use a leading `/` on the original topic you have to insert a double `/` in the shared subscription topic to insert the null, so just don't do it.

```
$share/backend//registration_app
```